# How to functionate the second activity through a radio button in the Main_activity?

Tags: java, android

if I have two activities.
1.Main_Activity
   which contain a radio button and an image button.
2.Second_activity extended from Main_activity.

which is intent in Main_activity and contain three radio buttons with the saved state in shared preference.
the vibration, normal and silent mode work on these radio buttons.
the Drvset activity is already intent through the image button.

I want to retrieve the saved state of the radio buttons and Load it through the radio button in the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton buttonOne = findViewById(R.id.drvedit);    
        RadioButton buttondr=findViewById(R.id.drvbtn);

        buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Button Clicked");
                Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), drvset.class);
                startActivity(activity2Intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class drvset extends MainActivity {

    private RadioButton normal;
    private RadioButton silent;
    private RadioButton vibrate;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;

    final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drvset);

        LoadPreferences();

        normal = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioNormal);
        silent = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSilent);
        vibrate=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiovibrate);

       normal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              normalEnable(v);
            }
        });
        silent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                silentEnable(v);
            }
        });
        vibrate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vibrateEnable(v);
            }
        });
        myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    }
    public void vibrateEnable(View view){
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        status.setText("Current Status: Vibrate Mode");
    }
    public void normalEnable(View view){
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        status.setText("Current Status: Ring Mode");
    }
    public void silentEnable(View view){
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        status.setText("Current Status: Silent Mode");
    }
                }};
    public void SavePreferences(String key, int value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
        RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This isn't any clearer than the first question, really, but my suggestion still stands: `MainActivity` can use the same `SharedPreferences` that `drvset` is using. Whatever data you need to share between the Activities, simply save it in one, and read it in the other, using `getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)` in both.

Comment: @MikeM. yes you are right but what if i have two extended activities from main activities with same normal silent and vibration in both, should i use one share preference or use individual for each activity?

Comment: actually  i had used one for all but the problem i faced was when i click silent mode in activity it was automatically changed in another one,

Comment: then i seperate the preferences , MYPREF1 for first activity and MYPREF2 for another then it work.

Comment: but still i have a problem that i want to retrieve that state saved in shared preference and want onclick() on button in main_activity.

Comment: Honestly, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, exactly, so I'm not sure that I can answer anything further. Firstly, for the given code, extending `MainActivity` for the other Activities is pointless, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve there. Secondly, one `RadioButton` by itself is rather useless, so I don't understand the function of `RadioButton buttondr` in `MainActivity`, nor how it's meant to relate to anything in the other Activities.

Comment: mean, when i click a radio button in main activity, It calls the state saved in the second activity. and performs a task either it is silent ,vibration or normal.

Comment: ohhh, the Radio button has no function yet, i want this radio button to call the state of the second activity. its all about to functionate this button,  @MikeM. anyway thank u,tnks fr support, never mind.